# How to get original object after modifying with dojo.clone?

Tags: dojo

I have a object which returns from service say, `studentInfo` (which has id 1).

I have cloned as below:

```
this.studentsInformation=dojo.clone(studentInfo);
```

Now I try to update the cloned object - `studentInfo` 
I have updated (say for id 1) and stored in database. If I create a new student info and  try to update in a db, it has to go with id 2. But the object has id 1...

And also if I print this.studentsInformation, it is not showing the original object.. it has got modified object only..

So I want the original object after modifying and also I want to store the updated information after cloning as well. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

why dont you store a reference in the clone to the original object ?

```
this.studentsInformation=dojo.clone(studentInfo);
this.studentsInformation.myMama=studentInfo;
```

Lucian

Comment: sorry, i don't understand your second line of code.... which is the original object here.. which will have original object and which will have modified object?

Comment: studentsInformation is your cloned object. studentsInformation contains in myMama a reference to the original object ! try it !

Comment: is it an efficient solution for this as we are creating one more reference called myMama?

Comment: its only a reference ! this is only a pointer to the object ! just what you desired..

Lucian